# Passing Complex object in post method for header application/x-www-form-urlencoded in ionic 2 and above

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to send post object to webapi which is expecting array of object inside a object i know how to send it in normal Ajaxcall but not able to find it in Ionic2.

Let me show you how my API server is expecting data

I have two class

First Class

```
public class class1{
    public long? variable1{ get; set; }
    public long? variable2{ get; set; }
    public int variable3{ get; set; }
    public string variable4{ get; set; }
    public string variable5{ get; set; }
    public decimal? variable6{ get; set; }
}
```

Second Class

```
public class class2
{
    public long? newvariable1{ get; set; }
    public int? newvariable2{ get; set; }
    public long? newvariable3{ get; set; }
    public long? newvariable4{ get; set; }
    public List<class1> newvariable5{ get; set; }
}
```

And Controller Will be

```
[HttpPost]
    public dynamic Post([FromBody] class2 value)
    {


 }
```

In ionic2 Post method i amble to send data to all parameter of class2 but not the parameter with datatype as class1.

Ionic2 Post method is as show below

```
  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  let body={
            newvariable5:JSON.stringify(this.ValueList),
            newvariable1:value1,
            newvariable2:value2,
            newvariable3:value3,
            newvariable1:value4
          }
  for(let key in body){
            params.append(key,body[key]);
        }

  this.http.post(this.config.url + "ClassListAPK",params, {
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json())

            .subscribe(data => {

                resolve(data);
            });
```

I have also tried with

```
      params.append("newvariable1", value1.toString());
        params.append("newvariable2", value2.toString());
        params.append("newvariable3", value3.toString());
        for(let j=0;j<this.classlist.length;j++){

        params.append("newvariable5",JSON.stringify(this.vlueList[j]));

        }

        params.append("newvariable4",value4.toString());
```

Where valuelist will containing the parameter

```
export class valueList{
     variable1:any;
     variable2:any;
     variable3:any;
     variable4:any;
     variable5:any;
     variable6:any;
  }
```

I have tried two day's without any luck.
I am expecting some help from here.

Comment: just curious.. wouldnt it be better to use post for this ?

Comment: Sorry Suraj I didn't get you

Comment: why use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) which is to send through get requests... Send the data through post body

Comment: When i tried to send only body without URLSearchParams at the server end i got null value for all the parameter.

Comment: 1. dont use stringify for each property.. use it on the whole object. 2. it may also depend on how you are retrieving in the server side

Comment: Let me try with 1 st option. When it come to second option please give me a light on it.

Comment: did you test your api with a rest client to see if it is accessing post body correctly?

Comment: i have tested with postman tool which worked fine in that problem accrued when i tried to integrate to app

Comment: I have changed the code after creating the body i have used
let bodyObject={
                "value":body
            }
then i did JSON.stringify to bodyObject and sent to API body. Now in the server side all the parameter are coming as null